# How can I reach map's elements sequentially to use another map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, insert

Here is my map from Course class:

```
map<pair<string,int>,pair<string,Array> > matchMap;
```

In this map, I am getting course name,course hours,days,available hours in this day.

And here is my other map from Schedule class: (Schedule class inherited from course and student class):

```
map< string,map<string,pair<string,Array> > >  courseScList;
```

In this I am trying to reach student name,course name,course day whick i entered in matchMap map,available course hours which I entered in matchMap map.

I wrote a code like this to do this work:

```
    string c,s;
    list<string>::iterator studentLoc;
    map< string,map<string,pair<string,Array> > >::iterator last;
    map<pair<string,int>,pair<string,Array> >::iterator location;
    map< string,map<string,pair<string,Array> > >::iterator match;
    dummy1:
    cout<<"Enter the student name"<<endl;
    cin >> s;
    wrongCourse:
    cout<<"Enter the course names you want"<<endl;
    cin>>c;

    auto predicate = [&](auto& course) { return compareName(course, c); };
    studentLoc = find(getStudentList().begin(),getStudentList().end(),s);
    location = find_if(getMatchMap().begin(), getMatchMap().end(), predicate);
    if(studentLoc != getStudentList().end() || location != getMatchMap().end())
    {
        getCourseScList().insert(make_pair(s,{getMatchMap()[c],make_pair(getMatchMap().at(c))}));
    }
```

However I dont know how to reach the matchMap data sequentially in this new map.

```
getCourseScList().insert(make_pair(s,{getMatchMap()[c],make_pair(getMatchMap().at(c))}));
```

How can I organize the code to reach the data when I write the course name, matchMap map's data will inserted the CourseScList map data.

Comment: What does `getStudentList` and `getCourseScList` and `getMatchMap` return? If they return by value then they return copies of the original map, and modifying a copy won't modify the original. And even iterators won't be the same or equal as they reference different containers.

Comment: This is next to unreadable. Why not use some classes instead of pairs? And a bit of `auto` for iterator types?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude they return reference `map<pair<string,int>,pair<string,Array> >&getMatchMap()   /////   map< string,map<string,pair<string,Array> > > &getCourseScList()`

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 I am the learning phase

Comment: `cout<<"Enter the course names you want"<<endl; cin>>c;` -- You should really use more descriptive names, much more than `c` and `s`.

Comment: *I am the learning phase* -- I get the feeling that this program needs to be redesigned.  It is very confusing as to what you're trying to achieve.  Learning programming entails going through a design phase, and to me, this looks very convoluted.

Comment: @sonelektrikci This feedback is part of your learning :)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You are right. However for now i have to solve the problem :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 yeah thanks for feedback. Do you know how can i solve this problem? After i solve this, i will relearn the designing

Comment: No, I found the code hard to read, so I have moved on sorry. You are competing with thousands of other question-askers for my free time :)

Comment: @sonelektrikci -- You are approaching an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  It would be better if you told us what problem you're trying to solve (don't mention maps, pairs, etc.  just the problem) rather than you give us your "solution", and hope we understand it.

Comment: On the other hand, questions here have to be about concrete pieces of code, i.e. a solution attempt. Just saying "here is my goal, what is the code?" would be too broad. XY is over-invoked IMO. But context is good.

Comment: If you want a answer in time it probably would be best to _first_ redesign your application, because your code is really hard to read and understand. Probably you can solve your error in the process of redesinging too.